# isEqualToString can the items be swapped?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am just curious if there is a way to swap the two stings in this example?

```
// This works
for(eachArtist in artistCollection) {
if([objFirName isEqualToString: [eachArtist firName]]) NSLog(@"DELETE ....");
}
```

What I was trying to do was (see below) can this be done or is the above the only way?

```
[eachArtist firName isEqualToString: objFirName]
```

eachArtist.firName is a NSString within an array of objects, objFirName is a vanilla NSString.

gary

Comment: That second line is not correct Objective-C what do you mean [[eachArtist firName] isEqualToString: objFirName]

Comment: Mark, that is what I was after, I was being a muppet, I was forgetting to bracket the first argument. Sorry, still trying to get to grips with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have synthesized the `firName` property in the `Artist` implementation, the two approaches are equivalent.

That is:

```
[eachArtist firName]
```

is the same as

```
eachArtist.firName
```

If the `@property` is `@synthesize`-d in `Artist.m` and `readwrite` or `readonly` in `Artist.h`.

Since you are performing an `isEqualToString` predicate and not a less-than or greater-than predicate, it doesn't matter the order in which elements are in the predicate.

In mathematical terms, A = B if and only if B = A, for the purposes of comparing strings.

Comment: Chuck Thats exactly what I wanted. @Alex Reynolds, many thanks, the only reason for wanting to swap the positions was to make the code read better.